# 14.10, 15.04 - HDMI audio not working on Dell Vostro 3750 - nVidia card not detected by aplay -l

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

**Summary:** Sound card on nVidia is not detected by ALSA so even though video works on HDMI, no audio plays. It is detected in pci.

How can I get ALSA to detect the nVidia card?

Output of `aplay -l`

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `sudo lspci -H 1  |grep -A 1 VGA:`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Output of `lsmod|grep snd`

```
snd_hda_codec_realtek    72838  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    67835  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          29390  3 
snd_hda_controller     29557  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         105492  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hda_core           29851  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                91280  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25722  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                56638  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              28579  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    66629  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              14604  1 snd
```

**EDIT 1:** I've upgraded to 15.04 and the problem still persists